# Run subtasks before launching a job in cargo-make

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Makefile.toml

```ini
[config]
skip_core_tasks = true


[env]
CARGO_MAKE_EXTEND_WORKSPACE_MAKEFILE = true

[tasks.ui]
command = "trunk"
workspace = false
args = ["build", "-d", "static", "ui/index.html"]

[tasks.server]
command = "cargo"
workspace = false
cwd = "server"
args = ["build"]


[tasks.run]
workspace = false
depencies = ["ui"]
command = "cargo"
args = ["run", "-p", "server"]

# This does not work
[tasks.watch]
workspace = false
run_task = [{ name = ["ui", "server"], fork = true }, { name = "run" }]
watch = true
```

`[tasks.watch]` is meant to run watch build on my two packages "server" and "ui" and then start "server" after both have been compiled. My current implementation, however, hangs on first step and does not start the server after the build.

```
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Build File: <...>/Makefile.toml
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Task: ui
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Profile: development
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Execute Command: "trunk" "build" "-d" "static" "ui/index.html"
2024-01-23T14:37:02.860607Z  INFO  Starting trunk 0.18.4
2024-01-23T14:37:02.860722Z  INFO  starting build
2024-01-23T14:37:02.860888Z  INFO spawning asset pipelines
2024-01-23T14:37:02.976747Z  INFO building ui
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.06s
2024-01-23T14:37:03.068538Z  INFO fetching cargo artifacts
2024-01-23T14:37:03.174545Z  INFO calling wasm-bindgen for ui
2024-01-23T14:37:03.404759Z  INFO rust build complete
2024-01-23T14:37:03.405822Z  INFO applying new distribution
2024-01-23T14:37:03.406417Z  INFO ✅ success
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Build Done in 0.81 seconds.
[cargo-make][1] INFO - Execute Command: "cargo" "make" "--disable-check-for-updates" "--no-on-error" "--loglevel=info" "--profile=development" "--allow-private" "--skip-init-end-tasks" "--makefile" "<...>/Makefile.toml" "server"
[cargo-make][2] WARN - Found unknown key: tasks.?.default.depencies in file: <...>/Makefile.toml
[cargo-make][2] WARN - Found unknown key: tasks.?.run.depencies in file: <...>/Makefile.toml
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Calling cargo metadata to extract project info
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Cargo metadata done
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Build File: <...>/Makefile.toml
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Task: server
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Profile: development
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Execute Command: "cargo" "build"
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.08s
[cargo-make][2] INFO - Build Done in 0.40 seconds.
[cargo-make][1] INFO - Build Done in 1.60 seconds.
```

What is the correct task configuration for `[tasks.watch]`?